# Method MAX() from SQL to Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Hi i'm trying to convert this SQL script in Linq expression

but i don´t know how do the MAX method in Linq

someone can help me?

thank you!

```
SELECT c.Nome, 
       c.NumeroRG, 
       f.Tipo, 
       f.Descricao, 
       f.DataHora,
       f.IdCliente,
       c.IdCliente,
       f.IdFrequencia    
FROM Cliente c, Frequencia f
WHERE f.Tipo = 1
AND   c.IdCliente = f.IdCliente
AND   cast(f.DataHora as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
AND   f.IdFrequencia = (select MAX(fr.IdFrequencia) 
                        from frequencia fr 
                        where fr.IdCliente =c.IdCliente)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var query = from client in db.Cliente
            join freq in db.Frequencia
            on client.IdCliente equals freq.IdCliente
            where freq.Tipo == 1 
            && freq.DataHora.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
            && freq.IdFrequencia == db.Frequencia.Where(f => f.IdCliente == client.IdCliente)
                                                  Max(f => f.IdFrequencia)
            select new { .... };
```

Maybe you need to replace `DateTime.Now.Date`/`DateTime.Today` with [`SqlFunctions.DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx) if you use LINQ-To-Entities, but you haven't mentioned that.

Comment: `db.Frequencia.Max(f => f.IdCliente == client.IdCliente)` cannot work, can it? How would this know that two `Frequencia` objects should be compared by the `IdFrequencia` property? I think you'd need `db.Frequencia.Where(f => f.IdCliente == client.IdCliente).Max(f => f.IdFrequencia)`

Comment: in && freq.IdFrequencia == db.Frequencia.Max(f => f.IdCliente == client.IdCliente) I have a error message "Operator "==" connot be applied to opperands of type long and bool" =/

Comment: sorry.... :) worked fine! thank you 
            var query = from client in db.Cliente
                        join freq in db.Frequencia
                        on client.IdCliente equals freq.IdCliente
                        where freq.Tipo == true
                        && freq.DataHora.Value.Date == DateTime.Today.Date
                        && freq.IdFrequencia == db.Frequencia.Where(f => f.IdCliente == client.IdCliente).Max(f => f.IdFrequencia)
                        select new { Nome = client.Nome, Descricao = freq.Descricao };

Answer (score 0):

this worked well! thanks

```
        var query = from client in db.Cliente
                    join freq in db.Frequencia
                    on client.IdCliente equals freq.IdCliente
                    where freq.Tipo == true
                    && freq.DataHora.Value.Date == DateTime.Today.Date
                    && freq.IdFrequencia == db.Frequencia.Where(f => f.IdCliente == client.IdCliente).Max(f => f.IdFrequencia)
                    select new { Nome = client.Nome, Descricao = freq.Descricao };
```